# OpenCV Python streaming m3u8 lag

Tags: python, opencv, m3u8

I am using OpenCV to catch the M3U8 stream

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("https://bitdasha.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")


while (True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if (ret != True):
        break

    cv2.imshow("video", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25)== 27:
        break
```

However, the frames plays lag and it crashed every few seconds, I think it's because it is catching next .ts file. Can anyone tell me how to prevent the lag and crash? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error output when it crashes?

Comment: There is no error output, it will stop for few seconds then keep showing the next frame.